# Cannot get caching for static recources (CSS, images) does to work in Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure account with a Web Application that is in the very early stages of development.

I am using Google Pagespeed Insights to test for any performance issues ( https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ )

It tells me I don't have the cache set for my static resources. So I have enabled caching in the web.config file for my web application by adding the following code:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMaxAge="00.12:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Yet this does not work (I check the headers with Chrome Dev Tools).

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, got it figured out.
Had to take out the following code out of web.config:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
</handlers>
<httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600"/>
```

It was there from the ASP.NET 5 MVC project I set up earlier.